# Пересечение в диапазоне чисел Python

Tags: python

Не могу придумать изящного решения для проблемы:

Есть list c крайними значениями диапазона

```
a = [5,10]

b = [9,15]
```

как найти, что они имеют общие **9** и **10**.

я вижу, как создание из каждого листа `range()` и перебор вхождений через `for`, но проблема в том, что когда числа большие, перебор занимает много времени. Есть какие-то интересные решения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение совершенно очевидное, как и во все случаях поиска пересечений двух интервалов: от максимума левых до минимума правых

```
range(max(a[0],b[0]), min(a[1],b[1])+1, 1)
```

Comment: можно ли как-то через if проверить, что диапазон был создан? или надо проверять через for? это же создается класс, а не переменная

Comment: @JopaBoga Присвойте результат в переменную, например `rng` и потом проверяется просто: `if rng:` ...

Comment: @JopaBoga да, именно так - если пересечения не было, то диапазон будет пустой. Если нужен список - list(range...)